# Запуск скрипта Python из другого скрипта выдает ошибку

Tags: python-3.x, exec

Нужно запустить на выполнение скрипт из другого скрипта. Делаю так:

```
import get_pages.py
exec(get_pages.py)
```

Код из файла get_pages.py работает верно, но в конце выдает ошибку

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'get_pages.py'; 'get_pages' is not a package
```

В чем может быть проблема? Как по-другому можно запустить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7975511 — `exec` очень плохая практика для таких случаев + не нужно писать в импорте `.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, насколько это хорошая практика, но это работает:

```
import os
os.system("python get_pages.py")
```